# Remote mass installation

Tags: installation, remote-control

We are about to develop an application for one of our client, to be deployed on over way over hundreds of new phones.

I would like to know if can could use google for work (or any other method / service) to "remote mass deploy" this app with no user interaction, or at least minimal interaction (like just accept installation popup) using a list of device ids ?

Thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Maybe you take a look how https://f-droid.org is doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I work for a large company that uses Maas360 (https://www.maas360.com) to control company phones.  It has a variety of features including security policies and push  install of applications automatically.